# Is there a command to only flush iptables for INPUT rules?

Tags: firewall, iptables

I know that iptables -F will clear all the chains, but is there a way only to clear the rules for INPUT, leaving FORWARD and OUTPUT rules intact?

Answer (score 4):

reading the manual took 3 seconds and revealed 'iptables -F INPUT'. 

Happy hunting!

Comment: Googling took 2. Thanks for your answer.